# bash: nano: command not found

Tags: git, bash

Как установить `nano` для git на Windows?

Comment: это попытка «ткнуть пальцем в небо»: https://coderwall.com/p/ee-law/use-nano-from-git-bash-on-windows-d //  а вообще лучше уточнить в вопросе, откуда именно у вас в *ms/windows* взялась программа *bash*. тогда и ответ может быть более конкретным.

Comment: <sarcasm> выполнить `bash` потом `apt-get nano`. у меня в Win10 TP работает</sarcasm>

Comment: выполнить `git config core.editor notepad` и пользовать обычный блокнот.

Comment: @KoVAdim спасибо! круто! помогло!

Comment: @pavel спасибо - как-нибудь попробую

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nano` ставится не на «Git на Windows», а на [MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/msys) — порт окружения GNU (консоли, утилит и библиотек) под Windows. А сборка Git под Windows просто включает MSYS в свой комплект поставки.

О том, как установить *nano* в MSYS, хорошо описано в статье «[Nano with mingw32 for msysgit](https://web.archive.org/web/20140522160053/http://vijayparsi.wordpress.com/2012/03/07/nano-with-mingw32-for-msysgit)». Ниже приведён её перевод.

> Если вы ярый поклонник *git*-а и преданный фанат *nano*, но вынуждены работать под Windows, то вы можете разочароваться в *msysgit*. Он использует в качестве *git bash* оболочку, входящую в состав *mingw32 shell*, однако не предоставляет при этом возможность редактировать текстовые файлы с помощью *nano*. Вместо этого вас вынуждают использовать *vi* либо *vim*. К счастью, я нашёл способ решения данной проблемы.
>
> Скачайте «WinNT/9x binary, .zip format» cо [страницы загрузки *nano*](http://www.nano-editor.org/download.php). Распакуйте архив и переименуйте извлечённую папку `nano-2.x.x` в `nano`.
>
> Затем, переместите её в папку `share` *git*-а. В моём случае она располагалась по адресу `C:\Program Files\Git\share`. Там же вы найдёте подпапки `vi` и `vim`.
>
> Создайте на своём рабочем столе текстовый файл с именем `nano` (без расширения) и следующим содержимым:
>
> ```
> #!/bin/sh
> exec /share/nano/nano.exe "$@"
> ```
>
> Переместите файл в папку `bin` *git*-а. В моём случае она располагалась по адресу `C:\Program Files\Git\bin`.
>
> Наконец, запустите *git bash* и откройте в ней какой-нибудь текстовый файл с помощью *nano*.
>
> [image: Nano в MSYS]

Comment: могуче получилось! спасибище!